# Change application label font when using ActionBarsherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-fonts

I am trying to change the font of the Application label (I am using ActionBarSherlock as a library project in my application) and getting errors.

Following is code snippet where I am trying to set an external font, stored in assets, to the app label after setContentView().

```
mAppName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abs__action_bar_title);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/handsean.ttf");
mAppName.setTypeface(face);
```

Following is the error from the logcat. The error seems to be showing up on the line mAppName.setTypeface(face).

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18762): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18762): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.cheats/com.cheats.LandingPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at com.cheats.LandingPage.onCreate(LandingPage.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(18762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

I found the following declaration of the text view for the application label in abs__action_bar_title_item.xml :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/abs__action_bar_title"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Is this the right way to do it OR am I missing something ? Can some one advice ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A couple if(_var_ == null) checks wont hurt your code, you might be referencing the wrong layout constant or your font may not be found.

Comment: @Machinarius:  It is the TextView I believe because when I tried doing mAppName.setText() to it, nothing changed in the text. Now after this I am not sure what is the right way to access the textView from the sherlock library? Or is it something different that is required here ? Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Well, ive barely used sherlock myself, but i dont think this stems from your usage of the sherlock library. Are you sure the the textview is in fact where you expect it to be? Also, bear in mind you should be using findViewById and friends **after** calling setContentView, just in case.

Comment: @Machinarius : Well I am pretty sure that the declaration I have posted above is the one used in the library for the app label. Also I ma doing all the findViewById and stuff after setContentView.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a lot of trials I was able to get the reference of the textView in the below manner and now the font has changed :

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if(titleId == 0)
    titleId = com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__action_bar_title;

mAppName = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/handsean.ttf");
mAppName.setTypeface(face);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Android (MonoDroid - C#):

If you have problems getting `null` on the `TextView` it could be because the Android version, above code worked for me with Android 4.2 but didn't with 3.1.

This worked for me:

```
TextView title = FindViewById<TextView>(Resources.GetIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android"));
if (title == null) title = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.abs__action_bar_title);

if( title != null)
{
   Android.Graphics.Typeface face = Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/font.otf");
   title.SetTypeface(face, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Abhishek Sabbarwal works fine (< 3.x and >= 4.x) but, in a case, Honeycomb, it fails to find the Textview, as charlesbock pointed it out.

After debugging, it seems that this line gives a positive titleId that yet, does not match a TextView.

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

However, using this line, the TextView is successfully found

```
titleId = R.id.abs__action_bar_title;
```

Therefore, here is my code that works for any version

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if(titleId == 0 || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH))
{
    titleId = R.id.abs__action_bar_title;
}

final TextView appName = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
```